# App incompatible on Android 2.3

Tags: java, android

I have published an app in google play but i can't make it compatible with android 2.3 devices. Example: if i try to download my app with Samsung galaxy s2 with android 4.1 is all ok, instead when i try to download my app with the same device but with android 2.3.3 google play tell me: "app is not compatible with this version". I checked my manifest (android:minSdkVersion="9 android:targetSdkVersion="17") and i don't find nothing problems...what i have to do...thanks

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- n.b. android:installLocation="auto" Enable the user to save the App either on the Phone internal memory or on the SD card -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.t3lab.nolan"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

    <uses-sdk

        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <supports-screens                                 
    android:smallScreens="true"                    
    android:normalScreens="true"         
    android:largeScreens="true"            
    android:xlargeScreens="true"   
    android:resizeable="true"          
    android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
        android:required="true" />




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_A2dp"
            android:label="@string/A2DP_Title_Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_B2b"
            android:label="@string/BikeToBike_Title_Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_End"
            android:label="@string/End_Title_Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_Keypad"
            android:label="@string/Keypad_Title_Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_Login"
            android:label="@string/login_Title_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_Main"
            android:label="@string/Main_Title_Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_Phone"
            android:label="@string/Phone_Title_Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_Presentation"
            android:label="@string/Presentation_Title_Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_Radio"
            android:label="@string/Radio_Title_Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_Reconnecting"
                android:label="@string/Reconnecting_Title_Activity"

                android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_Retry"
                android:label="@string/Retry_Title_Activity"

                android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Activity_Showing_Device"
            android:label="@string/ShowingDevice_Title_Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.FrameActivity_Settings"
            android:label="@string/Fragment_Title_Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.t3lab.nolan.Service_Bluetooth"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Change your min SDK version to 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```
<uses-sdk

        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

to

```
<uses-sdk

        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk

        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Use minimum sdk version of version 8 and make target sdk to 18 (latest) to run your app